# how to diagnose exception in comptr release on application exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception, com, atl

I have application that is giving exception when application exits. Callstack shows that exception is coming from CComPtr::release when CoUnintialize is called.

```
>   ieframe.dll!ATL::CComPtr<IWebBrowser2>::Release()  + 0x5b bytes 
    ieframe.dll!CConnectionPoint::UnadviseAll()  + 0x131d0 bytes    
    ieframe.dll!CConnectionPoint::~CConnectionPoint()  + 0x18 bytes 
    ieframe.dll!CShellOcx::~CShellOcx()  + 0xf7 bytes   
    ieframe.dll!CWebBrowserOC::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x14 bytes 
    ieframe.dll!CAggregatedUnknown::CUnkInner::Release()  + 0x474a1 bytes   
    ole32.dll!CStdIdentity::ReleaseCtrlUnk()  Line 1149 C++
    ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::Disconnect(unsigned long dwType)  Line 3454  C++
    ole32.dll!CStdMarshal::DisconnectAndRelease(unsigned long dwType)  Line 3161 + 0x11 bytes   C++
    ole32.dll!COIDTable::ThreadCleanup()  + 0x31bed bytes   C++
    ole32.dll!FinishShutdown()  Line 1035   C++
    ole32.dll!ApartmentUninitialize(int fHostThread)  Line 1291 C++
    ole32.dll!wCoUninitialize(COleTls & Tls, int fHostThread)  Line 2709 + 0x7 bytes    C++
    ole32.dll!CoUninitialize()  Line 2632   C++
    imm32.dll!000007feff3832f2()    
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for imm32.dll] 
    msctf.dll!000007fefeea7d59()    
    ntdll.dll!RtlProcessFlsData()  + 0x84 bytes 
    ntdll.dll!LdrShutdownThread()  + 0x4b bytes 
    ntdll.dll!RtlExitUserThread()  + 0x38 bytes 
    IEShims.dll!NS_CreateThread::DesktopIE_ThreadProc()  + 0xd6 bytes   
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes
```

Exception is Access Violation

Have you guys  faced situation like this? What stragy I can apply to figure root cause of this?
 till now I have done following

- I used windbg , but exception I am getting in windbg is different what I getting here in VS2010 Actually exception is same "Access violation" but stack trace is different.I am not very expert at windbg to figure this out.Any pointers in windbg to trace it?
- I tried to remove some code but it also did not wok.

Comment: By the moment of `CoUninitialize` call you should have all COM activity terminated. You don't have it happening.

Comment: Heap corruption is quite sufficient to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happens because of wrong objects release order. Consider the following example: COM object A is meant to own COM object B, so the expected sequence is that object A is explicitly called `Release()` on and in it destructor it will call `Release()` on object B. Now when `CoUnintialize()` is called COM will force-release all COM objects in *some* sequence. So there's a chance that object B is called `Release()` first and now object A holds a dangling pointer to what it thinks is object B and so when object A `Release()` is called it tries to make use of the dangling pointer and runs into undefined behavior.

The solution so this problem is explicitly releasing objects in the right sequence before `CoUnintialize()` is called.

Comment: problem is that in this case CoUnintialize is not called from my code.I have put break point in my code on call to CoUnintialize and its never gets called. I get exception before that only.

Comment: As we can see from the stacktrace, some thread is getting destroyed, so are you using by any chance a worker thread? If not, that means that your main thread is ended, and if it does so without you invoking CoUninitialize, it is probably destroyed because of some serious error (so the runtime invokes ExitProcess).   As far as I can remember it is possible to set break-points on API functions like CoUninitialize. If you do that, you might get a better clue which code invokes CoUninitialize.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and after red

http://mfctips.com/2012/10/29/cfiledialogdomodal-causes-access-violation/

I suspect that the problem was to put QFileDialog  as a local variable of my Qmainwindow methods. Then I solved it putting my Qfiledialog as a private member of QMainwindow, like this:

// in MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

Q_OBJECT
......      
private:
......
QFileDialog *ptDialog;
..... 
}
```

So I gave a new QfileDialog to ptDialog in MainWindow constructor and call ptDialog->exec()  according my needs in  MainWindow methods,  as follow:

//in MainWindow.cpp

//constructor

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{    
.....
ptDialog=new QFileDialog(this, tr("Abrir Imagem"),QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), "Imagens (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)");
......
}
```

//any method that I want to use  QFileDialog

```
void MainWindow::LoadFile()
{
    if(ptDialog->exec())
    {
        SetFile(ptDialog->selectedFiles().first());

    }

}
```

I think, this way, the Qmainwindow will be released only in application end, avoiding the problem.